# Keywords don't show in authenticated requests

Tags: youtube-api

Using version 2 of the API. A while back I had to switch to oauth2 authentication to continue to get keywords in my JSON responses. I did that and it worked fine for a while, but now keywords have disappeared from authenticated requests. I confirmed that it was not just my code by testing at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html) announcing the change I see the keywords will only be available to authenticated users and then only on individual videos. I did some testing and requested an individual video sure enough there they were.